# Where quantum physics and Neuropsychology overlap?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-entanglement

I am a current student looking toward a degree in Neuropsychology. I also have a fascination with quantum physics because there is something nagging me that looking outward at the universe and then seismically smaller into atoms we can truly better understand ourselves, our brains, our personality, and where our consciousness comes from than where it goes when we "die".

How would others suggest I start in beginning to bridge the two topics? Quantum mechanics? Quantum entanglement? I barely know the basics (thanks Neil de Grasse Tyson for Star Talk) of quantum physics but where should I be starting to get a good foundation? I feel I have a fairly good grasp of where to go so neuropsychology, however, being the research nerd that I am, I am always interested in others' suggestions as well.

Thank you for your guided expertise!

Comment: What do you mean by consciousness?

Comment: Check out this @ [The Emerging Physics of Consciousness (The Frontiers Collection)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Emerging-Physics-Consciousness-Frontiers-Collection/dp/3540238905)

Comment: Also, [Roger_Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Penrose) --- [The emperor's new mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Mind) and [Shadows on the mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadows_of_the_Mind)

Comment: Start with your last math class, then the (rest of) the standard calculus track through differential equations and linear algebra, then basic electromagnetism, then QM. Shortcuts will lead you to preposterous nonsense conclusions all too common in the social sciences.

Comment: Thank you Brendan for all the recommendations I will check all of those our. I don't know if I have developed the correct language to accurately get the core of the question I haven't developed yet. With that complicated thought in mind, when I describe or talk about consciousness I am talking about the human experience. The collective of our experiences, thoughts, memories, down to DNA and the effects all of that has on our brain.

Comment: You need QM to understand the atom, and so on, but the levels of organization below the synapsis are likely  not important to understand the mind. But I think learning computational neuroscience and AI will give you a better insight into the mind.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you will be digging a dry well in this endeavor, for the following reasons.

The world of quantum physics takes hold in the realm of things smaller than an atom. Because energy scales as the inverse of distance, small objects get fundamentally associated with high energies. So the nucleus of an atom interacts with the rest of the world via gamma rays and high-energy particles. When one of these emerges from a nucleus due to quantum effects, it carries enough punch to completely destroy a protein molecule in, for example, the sheath protecting a nerve bundle, a synapse, or a cell lining the inside of your gut or your lungs. The results of these destructions, if frequent enough, are fatal: this is why for instance polonium-210 is an extremely deadly poison. it is communicating its presence to the rest of the universe by spitting out *alpha particles* with enough energy to promptly kill living cells.

This means that the quantum world's communication means are fundamentally incompatible with biology, i.e., the quantum world cannot transmit an influence to the world of neuropsychology except by visiting death upon it.

Comment: Thank you Niels Nielsen! Interesting answer.